# Completing System of Vectors to an Orthogonal Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to complete ((1, -2, 2, -3), (2, -3, 2, 4)) to an orthgonal basis.  I honestly don't really know how to do this.  This a practice problem to a test, were we haven't done problems related to this.  I know that an orthogonal basis has that for basis $(v_1, ... , v_n)$, $v_i\perp v_j$ for $i\ne j$.  So I'm assuming I'm working in $R^4$, as the question only specifies "Euclideam Spcae".  In terms of actually solving the problem, I'm strugging, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the definition of a basis?

Comment: It's a family of vectors S in a vector space V, and S is a basis if it is minimal spanning, maximally linearly independent, or if each vector can be written in a unique way as a linear combination of S @science

Answer (score 1):

here is what you can do. you already have two vectors $u = (1, -2, 2, -3)^T, v = (2,- 2, 3, 4)^T$ that are orthogonal. we will first find four orthogonal vectors; making them of unit length is easier.

what we will do is pick a vector $a$ and find the projection on to the space spanned by $u, v$ and subtract it. we can just start with $a = (1,0,0,0).$  so let $$a = ku + lv + w $$ with $l,k$ are to be chosen so that $u^Tw = v^Tw  = 0.$  that is $$k = u^Ta/u^Tu, l = v^Ta/v^Tv \to k = \frac 1{14}, l = \frac 1{33},\\ w =(1,0,0,0)^T - \frac 1{14}((1, -2, 2, -3)^T + \frac1{33}(2,- 2, 3, 4)^T$$

once you have $w,$ or a nice multiple of it,  we have $u, v, w$ orthogonal. now you can use another vector hopefully $(0,1,0,0)$ and do the same trick to find the fourth vector.

Comment: A questin about notation, what does the $^T$ mean?

Comment: @Jeff, is the transpose. row vector turns into a column vectors and vice versa. i always think of vectors as column vectors.  but it is harder to typeset column vectors so i use the transpose symbol.

Comment: Ahhhh ok thats sumple enough thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We set:
$$\begin{gathered}
  {e_1}{\text{ = (}}1, - 2,2, - 3) \hfill \\
  {e_2}{\text{ = }}(2, - 3,2,4) \hfill \\
  A = ({a_1},{a_2},{a_3},{a_4}) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
and solve:
$$\begin{gathered}
  {e_1} \cdot A = 0 \hfill \\
  {e_2} \cdot A = 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
This gives:
$$\begin{gathered}
  {a_1} = {\text{2 }}{a_3} - {\text{17 }}{a_{\text{4}}} \hfill \\
  {a_2} = {\text{2 }}{a_3} - {\text{10 }}{a_{\text{4}}} \hfill \\
  A = ({\text{2 }}{a_3} - {\text{17 }}{a_{\text{4}}},{\text{2 }}{a_3} - {\text{10 }}{a_{\text{4}}},{a_3},{a_4}) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
We may set:
$$\begin{gathered}
  {a_3} = 1 \hfill \\
  {a_4} = 0 \hfill \\
  {e_3}{\text{ = }}(2,2,1,0) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
Now with $$A = ({a_1},{a_2},{a_3},{a_4})$$ we solve:
$$\begin{gathered}
  {e_1} \cdot A = 0 \hfill \\
  {e_2} \cdot A = 0 \hfill \\
  {e_3} \cdot A = 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
This gives:
$$A = {a_4}( - 5,2,6,1)$$
Set ${a_4}=1$ and
$${e_4} = ( - 5,2,6,1)$$
then 
$$\{ {e_1},{e_2},{e_3},{e_4}\}$$
is a set of linear independent and orthogonal vectors.
We can now normalize:
$${f_1} = \frac{{{e_1}}}{{\sqrt {{e_1}.{e_1}} }},{f_2} = \frac{{{e_2}}}{{\sqrt {{e_2}.{e_2}} }},{f_3} = \frac{{{e_3}}}{{\sqrt {{e_3}.{e_3}} }},{f_4} = \frac{{{e_4}}}{{\sqrt {{e_4}.{e_4}} }}$$
so$$\{ {f_1},{f_2},{f_3},{f_4}\}$$
is an orthonormal base.
Gram-Schmidt process is used, in case a complete base is given.
But here we only have to solve two linear systems of equations, because
${e_1}$ and ${e_2}$ are orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

You (still) want Gram-Schmidt: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)

The idea roughly is to start with a vector and remove the part in its direction from the other vectors. Then continue in the same fashion with the next vector.

And you need have four linear independent vectors in total, that means at least two more.

You can keep those two, as they are orthogonal already. Let them name $v$ and $w$. Again you can add $e_1 = (1,0,0,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1,0,0)$ to have an initial set which is a base (not tested, but very likely, check the determinant of the four vectors to be non-zero, if in doubt).

But now:

$$
e_1' = 
e_1 
- \left(e_1 \cdot \frac{v}{\lVert v \rVert}\right) 
\frac{v}{\lVert v \rVert}  
- \left(e_1 \cdot \frac{w}{\lVert w \rVert}\right) 
\frac{w}{\lVert w \rVert}  
$$

$$
e_2' = 
e_2 
- \left(e_2 \cdot \frac{v}{\lVert v \rVert}\right) 
\frac{v}{\lVert v \rVert}  
- \left(e_2 \cdot \frac{w}{\lVert w \rVert}\right) 
\frac{w}{\lVert w \rVert}  
- \left(e_2 \cdot \frac{e_1'}{\lVert e_1' \rVert}\right) 
\frac{e_1'}{\lVert e_1' \rVert}  
$$
where $a \cdot b = a_1 b_1+a_2 b_2+a_3 b_3+a_4 b_4$ and $\lVert r \rVert = \sqrt{r \cdot r} = \sqrt{r_1^2 + r_2^2 + r_3^2 + r_4^2}$.

I get

\begin{align}
e_1' &= (0.823232, 0.292929, -0.232323, -0.075758) \\
e_2' &= (0, 0.40082, 0.48671, 0.057260)
\end{align}

and $\mbox{det}(v,w,e_1',e_2') = 14 \ne 0$, so this is a base of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Is $e_2$ supposed to be (0,1,0,0)$?  So then $v_3$ would follow the formula listed on that link essentially?